# Can't start new thread python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа перебирает 5 тысяч строк. На каждую строку получается запускается 1 новый потоп. Спустя 500-600 строк выдает can't start new thread и перестает работать. Как это решить?

```
import aminofix
import requests 
import time 
import threading 
from threading import Thread


def gg(): 
     wiki = lines.split(" ")
     devic = wiki[2]
     device = devic[0:82]
     print(device)
     client = aminofix.Client(device)
     print(wiki[0], wiki[1], wiki[2])
     try:
         client.login(wiki[0], wiki[1])
         print(client.sid)
         with open("sid.txt", "a") as file:
             sidd = str("sid=")+str(client.sid) 
             file.writelines(f"{str(sidd)}\n")
     except: pass

while True: 
    with open("accounts.txt", "r+") as file:
        for lines in file:
            threading.Thread(target=gg).start()
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаете слишком много потоков.
Вам нужно подождать, пока место для нового потока освободится.

```
while True: 
    with open("accounts.txt", "r+") as file:
        for lines in file:
            while threading.active_count()>MAX_THREADS:
                time.sleep(3)
            threading.Thread(target=gg).start()
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

Предварительно нужно будет задать переменной `MAX_THREADS` приемлемое значие (не больше, чем исполняющая машина позволяет запустить потоков одновременно)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) чтоб создать нужное количество потоков и переиспользовать освободившиеся.

```
import multiprocessing.dummy
pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(64)
....

def gg(line):
....

....
with open("accounts.txt", "r+") as file:
    pool.map(gg, file)
```